# getInputStream Character Limit

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

I am using the code below to read from HttpsURLConnection Request Body.  The problem I am running into is that the sResponseString variable in the code below is limited to only 1000 characters.  Is there a way to increase or bypass this limit?

````
    ```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    String sInputLine = "";             
    while ((sInputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        sResponseString += sInputLine;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: There is no such limit. The server is most likely refusing to send more than this.

Comment: Without disclosing proprietary information, are you able to give more of a clue: what was the format of the request, and what data *was* read in response?

Answer (score 1):

Neither your client-side code (as shown) or the HTTP/HTTPS protocol or the underlying TCP/IP transport impose a ~1000 character limit on the size of a response.

<sup>(HTTP and TCP/IP have no technical limits.  There are technical / practical limits due to the fact that you are assembling the result as a string in the heap.  For example, a Java `String` can be at most 2^31 - 1 characters. But this isn't relevant to your problem ...)</sup>

So if something is limiting the response size, it will be the remote server or proxy that your code is talking to.  As such, there is no general solution.  Your approach should be:

- Check the documentation for the web API you are talking to see if it gives the cause for the problem and offers solutions.
- If not, contact the people who provide the API and ask for their assistance.

---

> Is there a way to increase or bypass this limit?

Not unless you know what causes it; see above.  And possibly, not at all.

---

It would also be worth checking what is in the ~1000 characters you are currently getting.  It might be an "error" response of some kind rather than the content you are expecting, and *that* may explain why it is smaller than you are expecting.